# How to develop addons for Google earth?

Tags: plugins, add-on, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

i'd like to know any resources or any starting point to start developing addons/plugins for Google earth. i am **not** talking about **application development using Google earth API**. instead i want to create addons/plugins for GE such as flight simulator tour guides etc..

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

The COM API has been deprecated, and so the ways you can control the user experience in Google Earth are by either creating KML content (including robust Tours), or by using the plugin.

Can you be more specific with an example of what you are trying to accomplish that cannot be done using the plugin?

Comment: i want to add multi touch capability to Google earth. Microsoft Virtual Earth has that ability.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about extending the full Google Earth Application then you are out of luck.
You can use the depreciated COM API to make your own application that uses the full Google Earth - but this is not very advisable.

I realise that you said you are ot talking about application development using Google earth API - but that is pretty much the way to get what you desire - i.e. A Google Earth implementation that supports multi-touch.

Really I don't see any other way, sorry.